# How to document the "setState" function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, events, jsdoc

## Issue

I am trying to document events with [JSdoc](http://usejsdoc.org/tags-event.html). Here is the [example](http://usejsdoc.org/tags-event.html) I followed:

```
/**
 * Throw a snowball.
 *
 * @fires Hurl#snowball
 */
Hurl.prototype.snowball = function() {
    /**
     * Snowball event.
     *
     * @event Hurl#snowball
     * @type {object}
     * @property {boolean} isPacked - Indicates whether the snowball is tightly packed.
     */
    this.emit('snowball', {
        isPacked: this._snowball.isPacked
    });
};
```

Following that example, I documented my events as follows.

```
Inside a class named "Something"
/**
   Update state to include entered Thing Name
   @fires Something#handleThingChange
*/
  handleThingChange = (evt) => {
    /**
      handleThingChange event.

      @event Something#handleThingChange
      @type {updater}
      @property {string} state.thing
    */
    this.setState({ thing: evt.target.value });
  }
```

## Question

I am unsure on how to document the setState function.  Is it of type [updater](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#setstate)? Or does it warrant the [@callback](http://usejsdoc.org/tags-callback.html) tag?

Comment: why would the function's boilerplate affect the documentation of the function itself? we doc meaning and interaction, not mechanics.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your code i would say that it'll be of type `updater`.

**Explanation**

The `ReactComponent.setState` "updates" the current component state so it would be meaningful to document it as such. Yes the method has an optional `callback` parameter but i wouldn't take that into account because you don't use it.